# Can't send data-url src'd images as an html in gmail

Tags: html, image, gmail, src, data-uri

I'm sending an html email in gmail like so:

```
<html>
<body>
<h1>Hi</h1>
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZ..." alt="mystuff">
</body>
</html>
```

In the browser gmail, instead of seeing the image, I see the alt string, and the actual image tag shows up at the end of the html. However, when I use the macOS Mail email client, the images are shown. How can I send images as data-urls such that they show up in the browser gmail?